# How to know if a column is surrounded by double-quotes when making an update in Hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

When I make an update through the aplication by submitting a form then I get `invalid identifier exception`. Here is the entity concerned :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pta")
public class Pta {

    @Id()
    @SequenceGenerator(name="s_pta", sequenceName="s_pta", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="s_pta")
    @Column(name="pta_code")    
    private Long code;

    @Column(name="pta_intitule")
    @Lob
    private String lib;

    @Column(name="pta_ref")
    private String ref;

    @Column(name="pta_desc")
    @Lob
    private String descr;

    @Column(name="owner")
    private Long owner;

    @Column(name="creation")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date creation;

    @Column(name="modification")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date modification;

    @Column(name = "deleted")
    private Integer deleted;

    @Column(name = "pta_definitif")
    private Integer definitif;

    @Column(name="pta_num_credit")
    private String pta_num_credit;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "typ_proj_code")
    private TypeProjet typ_proj_code;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sect_code")
    private Secteur sect_code;

    @Column(name="pta_unite_execution")
    private String pta_unite_execution;

    @Column(name = "pta_activite")
    private Integer pta_activite;

    @Column(name="pta_signature")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date pta_signature;

    @Column(name="pta_vigueur")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date pta_vigueur;

    @Column(name="pta_limite_decaisse")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date pta_limite_decaisse;

    @Column(name="pta_cloture")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date pta_cloture;

    @Column(name="pta_resultat_annee")
    @Lob
    private String resultatAnnee;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="pta")
    private List<Ressource> ressources;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "class_pta_code")
    private ClassePta classePta;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
    private List<Pta> sousPtas;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="pta")
    private List<Objectif> objectifs;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "pta_pta_code")
    private Pta parent;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "struct_code")
    private Structure structure;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "responsable_tache" , joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "pta_code")} , inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "struct_code")} )
    private Set<Structure> responsables_tache = new HashSet<Structure>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "exer_code")
    private Exer exercice;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cdmt_code")
    private Cdmt cdmt;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "pta_pnd" , joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "pta_code")} , inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "pnd_code")} )
    private Set<Pnd> pnds = new HashSet<Pnd>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "pta_programme" , joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "pta_code")} , inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "prog_code")} )
    private Set<Pmo> pmos = new HashSet<Pmo>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "pta_effet_pmo" , joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "pta_code")} , inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "obj_code")} )
    private Set<Objectif> effets_pmo = new HashSet<Objectif>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "pta_produit_pmo" , joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "pta_code")} , inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "obj_code")} )
    private Set<Objectif> produits_pmo = new HashSet<Objectif>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "pta_objectif_ddp" , joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "pta_code")} , inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "obj_code")} )
    private Set<Objectif> ddps = new HashSet<Objectif>();

    public Pta() {
        super();
    }

    public Pta(Long code) {
        super();
    }

    public Long getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(Long code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public Structure getStructure() {
        return structure;
    }

    public void setStructure(Structure structure) {
        this.structure = structure;
    }

    public Set<Structure> getResponsables_tache() {
        return responsables_tache;
    }

    public void setResponsables_tache(Set<Structure> responsables_tache) {
        this.responsables_tache = responsables_tache;
    }

    public Exer getExercice() {
        return exercice;
    }

    public void setExercice(Exer exercice) {
        this.exercice = exercice;
    }

    public Cdmt getCdmt() {
        return cdmt;
    }

    public void setCdmt(Cdmt cdmt) {
        this.cdmt = cdmt;
    }

    public String getLib() {
        return lib;
    }

    public void setLib(String lib) {
        this.lib = lib;
    }

    public String getRef() {
        return ref;
    }

    public void setRef(String ref) {
        this.ref = ref;
    }

    public String getDescr() {
        return descr;
    }

    public void setDescr(String descr) {
        this.descr = descr;
    }

    public Long getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(Long owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public Date getCreation() {
        return creation;
    }

    public void setCreation(Date creation) {
        this.creation = creation;
    }

    public Date getModification() {
        return modification;
    }

    public void setModification(Date modification) {
        this.modification = modification;
    }

    public Integer getDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(Integer deleted) {
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }

    public Integer getDefinitif() {
        return definitif;
    }

    public void setDefinitif(Integer definitif) {
        this.definitif = definitif;
    }

    public List<Ressource> getRessources() {
        return ressources;
    }

    public void setRessources(List<Ressource> ressources) {
        this.ressources = ressources;
    }

    public ClassePta getClassePta() {
        return classePta;
    }

    public void setClassePta(ClassePta classePta) {
        this.classePta = classePta;
    }

    public List<Pta> getSousPtas() {
        return sousPtas;
    }

    public void setSousPtas(List<Pta> sousPtas) {
        this.sousPtas = sousPtas;
    }

    public List<Objectif> getObjectifs() {
        return objectifs;
    }

    public void setObjectifs(List<Objectif> objectifs) {
        this.objectifs = objectifs;
    }

    public Pta getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Pta parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Set<Pnd> getPnds() {
        return pnds;
    }

    public void setPnds(Set<Pnd> pnds) {
        this.pnds = pnds;
    }

    public Set<Pmo> getPmos() {
        return pmos;
    }

    public void setPmos(Set<Pmo> pmos) {
        this.pmos = pmos;
    }

    public Set<Objectif> getEffets_pmo() {
        return effets_pmo;
    }

    public void setEffets_pmo(Set<Objectif> effets_pmo) {
        this.effets_pmo = effets_pmo;
    }

    public Set<Objectif> getProduits_pmo() {
        return produits_pmo;
    }

    public void setProduits_pmo(Set<Objectif> produits_pmo) {
        this.produits_pmo = produits_pmo;
    }

    public Set<Objectif> getDdps() {
        return ddps;
    }

    public void setDdps(Set<Objectif> ddps) {
        this.ddps = ddps;
    }

    public String getPta_num_credit() {
        return pta_num_credit;
    }

    public void setPta_num_credit(String pta_num_credit) {
        this.pta_num_credit = pta_num_credit;
    }

    public TypeProjet getTyp_proj_code() {
        return typ_proj_code;
    }

    public void setTyp_proj_code(TypeProjet typ_proj_code) {
        this.typ_proj_code = typ_proj_code;
    }

    public String getPta_unite_execution() {
        return pta_unite_execution;
    }

    public void setPta_unite_execution(String pta_unite_execution) {
        this.pta_unite_execution = pta_unite_execution;
    }

    public Integer getPta_activite() {
        return pta_activite;
    }

    public void setPta_activite(Integer pta_activite) {
        this.pta_activite = pta_activite;
    }

    public Date getPta_signature() {
        return pta_signature;
    }

    public void setPta_signature(Date pta_signature) {
        this.pta_signature = pta_signature;
    }

    public Date getPta_vigueur() {
        return pta_vigueur;
    }

    public void setPta_vigueur(Date pta_vigueur) {
        this.pta_vigueur = pta_vigueur;
    }

    public Date getPta_limite_decaisse() {
        return pta_limite_decaisse;
    }

    public void setPta_limite_decaisse(Date pta_limite_decaisse) {
        this.pta_limite_decaisse = pta_limite_decaisse;
    }

    public Date getPta_cloture() {
        return pta_cloture;
    }

    public void setPta_cloture(Date pta_cloture) {
        this.pta_cloture = pta_cloture;
    }

    public String getResultatAnnee() {
        return resultatAnnee;
    }

    public void setResultatAnnee(String resultatAnnee) {
        this.resultatAnnee = resultatAnnee;
    }

    public Secteur getSectCode() {
        return sect_code;
    }

    public void setSectCode(Secteur sectCode) {
        this.sect_code = sectCode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(code);
    }   

}
```

Here is the database table associated to it :

```
create table pta 
(
   pta_code             number(15)           not null,
   sect_code            number(15),
   struct_code          varchar2(15),
   cdmt_code            varchar2(15),
   typ_proj_code        number(5),
   class_pta_code       number(5)            not null,
   pta_pta_code         number(15),
   mode_real_code       number(10),
   exer_code            varchar2(4)          not null,
   pta_ref              varchar2(25),
   pta_intitule         clob,
   pta_definitif        smallint,
   pta_desc             clob,
   pta_comment          clob,
   owner                integer,
   creation             date,
   modification         date,
   deleted              smallint             default 0,
   pta_signature        date,
   pta_vigueur          date,
   pta_limite_decaisse  date,
   pta_cloture          date,
   pta_num_credit       varchar2(50),
   pta_unite_execution  varchar2(255),
   pta_activite         smallint   default 1,
   pta_resultat_annee   clob,
   constraint pk_pta primary key (pta_code)
);
```

The invalid identifier exception is on the pta_resultat_annee column.

This exception occurs generally when making an update with column surrounded by double-quotes. So what in my code is wrong ?

**update :**

here is what is executed by the application by using Hibernate :

```
Hibernate: update pta set cdmt_code=?, class_pta_code=?, creation=?, pta_definitif=?, deleted=?, exer_code=?, modification=?, owner=?, pta_pta_code=?, pta_activite=?, pta_cloture=?, pta_limite_decaisse=?, pta_num_credit=?, pta_signature=?, pta_unite_execution=?, pta_vigueur=?, pta_ref=?, sect_code=?, struct_code=?, typ_proj_code=?, pta_desc=?, pta_intitule=?, pta_resultat_annee=? where pta_code=?
```

Comment: is it a json data. can you please post the sample data which is causing the break.

Comment: it is a form submitted data ; see the update in the post for the data.